# Tips for improving Windows 7 performance on a netbook

Tags: windows-7, netbook

Windows 7 doesn't run very well on my HP Mini (Atom 280N with 2GB DDR2).

Does anyone have anyor any tips for improving the general performance of Windows 7 on netbooks?

Comment: Do you mean a Dell Mini, or just netbooks in general? What make and model? What specs? What applications are you running? If you want a detailed answer, you need to ask a detailed question.

Comment: Also, are you experiencing any specific areas where you would like to improve performance (startup, app startup, general operation of certain specific apps, disk access, ...)

Comment: I've been tweaking the question a little bit, this way I actually don't think it's a bad question, just need to find more answers. Actually I think I'll split my answer up in multiple parts

Comment: Voila, now people can upvote the tips that are actually a good idea and downvote the bad ones

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Fine Tune Visual Graphics/Animation Settings**

[image]

The Windows 7 eye candy is the main
 cause of GUI slowness. While my
 netbook has a decent graphics card
 that can display Aero Glass it can be
 choppy at times.

Click on the Start Button and type in
 adjust the appearance and hit Enter.
 This will load the Visual Effects
 performance options.

On this screen I suggest disabling the
 following settings by removing the
 check:

- Animate controls and elements inside windows
- Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
- Fade or slide menus into view
- Fade or slide ToolTips into view
- Fade out menu items after clicking
- Show window contents while dragging
- Slide open combo boxes
- Click OK when you are finished.

[From TaranFX](http://www.taranfx.com/tweaking-your-windows-7-for-netbooks-top-5-tweaks)

Comment: Disabling Aero also seems to provide a slight speed increase. Click on Start, type "disable aero", select "Enable or disable transparent glass on windows" and then de-select the "Enable transparency" option.

Answer (score 6):

**Disable Services**

As Molly mentioned: have a look at [Blackviper.com](http://www.blackviper.com/) so you know what to turn off and why.

**[Here are some notes for a Happier Computer and User on tweaking services](http://www.blackviper.com/Windows_7/servicecfg.htm)**

- Do not use "msconfig" to disable services, type "services.msc" in the Run box instead or [check this FAQ!](http://www.blackviper.com/2009/01/27/windows-7-how-do-i-change-the-automaticmanualdisabled-function/)
- Before disabling any service, check out the [service information](http://www.blackviper.com/windows-default-services/windows-7-default-services/) about each by selecting the service name links provided.
- Service settings are **global**, meaning changes apply to all users.
- All of these services are "Standard" with Windows 7 and installed by default, by Add/Remove Windows Features, or installed via Windows Live Essentials. If you discover a service that is not listed here, another application, driver or program installed them. A few of the more common ones [are listed here](http://www.blackviper.com/2009/01/13/windows-7-strange-service-and-process-information/).
- [WLAN Autoconfig](http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/wlan-autoconfig/) service is required for normal operation of your wireless network card. It is listed here as Manual due to most desktops not needing wireless access, but if you do have a wireless network card installed, it will be in Automatic by default.
- Still unsure? Put your setting to "Manual" or the listing under "Safe." Manual allows Windows 7 to start the service when it needs to (or when ever it feels like it), but not at boot up. Depending on your configuration, not all services will start when required while in "Manual" mode. If you find you need a service, place it in Automatic.
- **After adjusting your service settings, reboot your computer.**

---

**Aren't afraid to brick your system and have full confidence in whatever I link?**

Try the following:

[image]

Now it’s time to trim the Windows
 services running in the background of
 your computer.

Click on the Start Button and type in
 services.msc and hit Enter.

When the Services management console
 is shown you can stop and disable
 services by selecting the service,
 right clicking and selecting
 Properties. Then change the Startup
 type to Disabled and hit the Stop
 button. Finally click OK to return to
 the Services management console.

I recommend disabling the following
 services on a netbook:

- Block Level Backup Engine Service
- Certificate Propagation
- Homegroup Provider
- Offline Files
- Portable Device Enumerator Service
- Software Protection
- SSDP Discovery
- Windows Defender
- Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service
- Windows Search

Other services you can play around
with:

1. Application Experience
2. Computer Browser
   3.Error Reporting Service
3. Desktop Window Manager Session Manager
4. Diagnostic Policy Service
5. IP Helper
6. Offline Files
7. Portable Device Enumerator Service
8. Print Spooler
   10.Distributed Link Tracking Client
9. Protected Storage
   12.Secondary Logon
10. Server (If your computer do not connect with any network)
11. Tablet PC Input Service
12. Themes
13. TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
14. Windows Media Center Service Launcher
15. Windows Search
    19.Remote Registry
16. Windows Time
17. Windows security center
18. Windows updates
19. Windows firewall (Provided you have a security software installed)

You can disable more services which you feel
 you won’t use. Keep in mind that if
 you use any of these services or
 applications that depend on them they
 will no longer function. E.g. if you
 are a homegroup user don’t disable the
 Homegroup Provider.

[From TaranFX](http://www.taranfx.com/tweaking-your-windows-7-for-netbooks-top-5-tweaks)

Comment: that is a rather poor 'service tweak guide'. you don't explain the implications and dependencies. for example: if you disable Windows Defender, it will cause an error message at startup (unless you disable the corresponding startup entry with Autoruns). better go to blackviper.com.

Comment: You're more than welcome making it into something more complete ;-)

Comment: as i said, send 'em off to blackviper.com, it doesn't get any better :)

Answer (score 4):

**Remove Startup Programs**

Nothing wastes resources more is
 startup programs that you don’t need.
This can be done multiple ways, the easy way is using CCleaner:

[CCleaner (Free)](http://www.ccleaner.com/)

[image]

> [CCleaner isn't strictly a startup](http://lifehacker.com/5425289/five-best-startup-management-tools)
>   management tool. Most people use it to
>   clean out cookies and other
>   undesirable elements and to tidy up
>   the registry. A secondary but helpful
>   tool in CCleaner: it also allows you
>   to delete entries from the startup
>   file—hence its inclusion here. It's a
>   bit of a one trick pony, though; you
>   can't alter, tweak, or insert entries.
>   You can only delete them. Still, it
>   gets the job done if the task you want
>   isn't advanced tweaking, but just to
>   get that annoying program to stop
>   popping up every time you reboot.

Alternatively you can use follow these steps:

Click on the Start Button and type in
 msconfig and hit Enter.

When the System Configuration utility
 is loaded click on the Startup tab.

Remove the check next to any
 applications you don’t need and click
 OK.

[image]

[From TaranFX](http://www.taranfx.com/tweaking-your-windows-7-for-netbooks-top-5-tweaks)

Comment: the system configuration utility is not a startup manager.

Comment: Doesn't the Window say System configuration? But I'll edit in CCleaner to do it

Comment: Try Autoruns :)

Answer (score 4):

**Turn off Windows features**

[image]

Microsoft gives you much more
 flexibility with Windows 7, allowing
 you to turn off Windows components —
 such as Internet Explorer, Windows
 Search, the Gadget platform, and media
 features — that you couldn’t disable
 in earlier versions of Windows. Here’s
 how:

Click Start | Control Panel and select
 Programs And Features. In the left
 pane, click Turn Windows Features On
 Or Off. Simply select or deselect the
 check boxes to enable or disable the
 various Windows features then click
 OK.

You can easily turn Windows features
 on or off in Windows 7.

[From TaranFX](http://www.taranfx.com/tweaking-your-windows-7-for-netbooks-top-5-tweaks)

Answer (score 2):

Molly, just because you don't use msconfig for stopping services, doesn't mean that you don't use msconfig for cleaning up your startup. msconfig IS how you control your startup programs. Most programs can be prevented from running on start up from their own options menu. If not then you use msconfig. You are misinterpreting the guy from the site you're referencing. And it is a bit misleading to people coming here for advice. They will think they shouldn't ever use msconfig to clean up their startup programs.

Link to site to substantiate statement.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/removing-startup-programs-in-windows-7/c2ff3fd1-3e32-46d9-9522-ec05034a2db1