# windows 7 speed up - how to?

Tags: windows-7, performance, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any tips to improve Windows 7 performance on a netbook](https://superuser.com/questions/99580/any-tips-to-improve-windows-7-performance-on-a-netbook)

hey, im looking for a software like tuneup utils to improve my speed of my pc, i did some uninstalls and stuff but i want to clean up all the junk i got from past software and do some registry improvement,.. anyone can recommend on a app?

Answer (score 0):

- Open msconfig. Go to Services, click hide all microsoft services and uncheck unwanted services. Go to startup tab and uncheck unwanted startups. Hit Apply and restart pc.
- Perform disk cleanup.
- Perform defrag.
- Run your antivirus software and check for malware/adware, etc...

I wouldn't recommend tune up utils coz most of the time, they screw things up... :)